# need to return the first record linq

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I need to return only the first record. Although I had to put the z.FirstOrDefault(); still more than one were displayed

```
           public DataTable GetDependents(string EmployeeID)
    {
        HealthCareSystem.DataClassesDataContext db = new HealthCareSystem.DataClassesDataContext();

        var z = (from s in db.SelectingDependentsGroupBies
                 where s.EmployeeID.Equals(EmployeeID)
                 join d in db.Dependents on s.DependentID equals d.DependentID
                 orderby s.DependentID descending

                 //Selecting wanted tables dependents fields by datatable
                 select new DependentsX { DependentID = Convert.ToInt32(s.DependentID), EmployeeID = s.EmployeeID, Name = s.Name, Surname = s.Surname, IDCardNo = s.IDCardNo, ContactNo = s.ContactNo, BirthDate = s.BirthDate, StartSchemeDate = s.StartDate, EndSchemeDate = s.EndDate, RelationType = s.Type, Payment = Convert.ToDouble(d.Payment), });

        var firstRecord = z.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: When you debug this code, hover over `var z` and tell us what type it says it is.

Comment: Also, your return type is DataTable and the end of your method you are instead trying to get a single `DependentsX` object.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line after your existing code:

```
var firstRecord = x.First();
```

If there might be zero results and you don't want an exception then you can use `FirstOrDefault` instead.

```
var firstRecord = x.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Still with the problem :( Can the problem be because I have a datatable after it?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Can you post the full code and the error message?

Comment: @user1542323: Post it in your question.

Comment: it is giving me problems to post the whole problem :(

Comment: then I am having this for loop I dont know if I am clear enough. Thanks alot. Sry for the hassel but Im a beginner... thankss

Answer (score 0):

Another common way is to enclose your query in parenthesis and then include the extension methods outside the parenthesis:

```
var x = (from d in db.DependentsRelationsViews 
        where d.IDCardNo.Equals(DepID) 
        orderby d.DependentID descending 
        select new DependentsX  
        {  
            DependentID = Convert.ToInt32(d.DependentID),  
            EmployeeID = d.EmployeeID,  
            Name = d.Name,  
            Surname = d.Surname,  
            IDCardNo = d.IDCardNo,  
            ContactNo = d.ContactNo,  
            BirthDate = d.BirthDate,  
            StartSchemeDate = Convert.ToDateTime(d.StartSchemeDate),  
            EndSchemeDate = d.EndSchemeDate,  
            Payment = d.Payment,  
            RelationType = Convert.ToString(d.Type) 
        }).FirstOrDefault();
```

If you don't enclose it in parenthesis and try to call `FirstOrDefault()` then you're applying that extension to the anonymous type in just the very last `Select` clause. By enclosing the whole query in parenthesis and then calling the `FirstOrDefault()` extension, you're indicating to the compiler that you wish to apply it to the return value of your entire query, which will be the `IEnumerable<>` or `IQueryable<>` collection.

Comment: I tried it but then it is giving me this Error 18 'HealthCareSystem.DependentsX' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'HealthCareSystem.DependentsX' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Acer 20 sep\Desktop\Health on Laptop\HealthCareSystem\DataAccess.cs 558 41 HealthCareSystem

Comment: That's because you can't call ToList() on a single item. It works on `IEnumerable<T>`. Why do you need a list when you only want the first record?

Comment: I am calling multiple dependents which have the same Employee ID for an example: 
Name Surname DependentID and EMPID Scheme 
Mark Calleja 0045M 00456M A 
Ian Zammit 0090M 00456M   A
Mark Calleja 0045M 00456M B

Comment: @user In the question you state that you want just the first dependent.  Is this not true?